# What are these insects on my pepper plants?

Tags: identification, insects, peppers

They seem to have come out of nowhere in the past week.

[image: Long-legged green insects]

Comment: Are they actually hurting the plants? They look kind of like squash bug nymphs or something.

Answer (score 1):

looks like what they call "leaf footed bug, nymphs"

Comment: Hi Todd, the main question was, "are they hurting the plant"

Comment: I only see a question asking what the insects are, and an answer to that question.  "Last seen more than a month ago" :-(